# Flexbox mobile footer with input causes virtual keyboard gap

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox, mobile-website

I have an extremely simple flexbox based layout with a div and a footer. The footer has an input box in it. Whenever the keyboard comes up in mobile safari or chrome a small gap is shown betwixt the body and the keyboard. Does anyone know how to remove this horrible gap?

Please see the follow JS Bin on your device: http://jsbin.com/rujexadodu/edit?html,css,js,output

[image: Out]

Full code

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
  <style type="text/css">

  html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid pink;
  }

  .container {
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .footer {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .content {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    This is the body content.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What do you see if you inspect it?

Comment: What version of iOS? I don't see he problem on my iPad

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this on my iPad and nothing is jumping out as wrong in your code. So it might just be a bug in what ever version of Safari you have.

I wrote a library call iFrame-resizer that keeps an iFrame height matched to the content size and working out the content height in different browsers is so unreliable that I have to provide 10 different ways of working it out.

It's not a complete fix, however, setting the background color of the `body` and `html` elements to match the footer would make it much less noticeable.

Comment: I don't think if this is really an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this so it must be a browser issue.
Here are a couple of things that may help:

Depending on your version of safari, you may need to prefix flexbox:

```
display: -webkit-box; /* Really old */
display: -moz-box; /* Firefox */
display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE */
display: -webkit-flex; /* Chrome & Safari */
display: flex;
```

and the flex value:

```
-webkit-box-flex: 1 0 auto;
-moz-box-flex:  1 0 auto;
-webkit-flex:  1 0 auto;
-ms-flex:  1 0 auto;
flex:  1 0 auto;
```

You need to give `flex` three values for it to work properly too, they are `grow`, `shrink`, and `basis`, in that order.  The default is to allow grow, disallow shrink, and the size to start at 'auto' `1 0 auto`.

I think flexbox still works if you don't put flex values on the children, but different browsers can have quirks... so I would make sure that the footer has

```
flex: 1 0 auto;
```

rather than

```
display: flex;
```

Some links that I find useful:

- [A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [A flexbox mixin for SASS](https://github.com/mastastealth/sass-flex-mixin)